# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML onClick not working

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am very new to react just trying to add onClick inside the html render by the dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Here is the code example

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const hello = (event) => {
    alert("hello", event.target);
  };
  const displayUrl = () => {
    const str = `<a onClick=${hello} href="#">Test</a>`;
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: str }} />;
    //return `<a href='#'>Test</a>`;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <React.Fragment>{displayUrl()}</React.Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-dew-hxl31?file=/src/App.js)

Please help me to understand why it's not working

Comment: Your string element has `onClick` (in vanilla html it's `onclick`), you are also missing wrapping quotes. But... if you are new, I would suggest avoiding this entirely, it will likely be removed soon and should not be relied on.

Comment: thanks for your comment how can make it work for now to understand it please

Comment: This is not a valid use-case for `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. *how can make it work for now* - **don't**. Use normal JSX.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting an `onClick` listener, which is React in HTML. To run javascript after a click event, you're better off using the `<button>` element.

Try something like this:

```js
const displayUrl = () => {
  const str = ` <button onclick="${hello}">Click me</button> `
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: str }} />
};
```

Please keep in mind that using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` isn't best practice. I would follow Henry Woody's answer.

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in the comments (and as indicated by the property name), you should avoid using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as much as possible (I would say don't use it at all until you understand React very well). Here there is a straightforward React approach to setting the `onClick` function on an element.

You need to render the element with the `onClick` normally and just pass `onClick` as a prop.

For example:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const hello = (event) => {
    alert("hello", event.target);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={hello}>Click here</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

With a link (as your sandbox has and question suggests), you can use the `a` element and set the `href` to the desired URL.

For example:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const url = "http://example.com"

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <a href={url}>Click here</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And `url` can come from anywhere you'd like (e.g. props or fetched from somewhere and held in state).

Comment: thank you for the update what if the text is coming from API and we have to render it ?

Comment: The text as in what I currently have as "Click here" or the URL?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you want @MetaMk? it's different to fetch some info on click than adding an element on click to display info